# PHP end div after X amount of divs and start new one after X divs

Tags: php, html, css, loops, grid

I am trying build an asymmetrical grid with a php loop.

I have managed to do this:

```
<?php
$arr = array("blue", "yellow", "red", "pink", "green", "cyan", "gold", "orange", "magenta","blue", "yellow", "red", "pink", "green", "cyan", "gold", "orange", "magenta","blue", "yellow", "red", "pink", "green", "cyan", "gold", "orange", "magenta");

$i = 0;
foreach ($arr as $val) {

    if($i <= 4) {
        if($i%2 == 0) {
            if($i != 0) {
                echo "</div>";
            }
            echo '<div class="container" style="margin:20 10px;border:1px solid;">';
        }
    }
    if($i%7 == 0) {
        if($i != 0) {
            echo "</div>";
            echo '<div class="container" style="margin:20 10px;border:1px solid;">';
        }   
    }
    ?>
    <div class="holder" style="font-family:helvetica;font-weight:bold;padding:5px;background-color:<?php echo $val; ?>;">
        <?php echo $i." - ".$val;?>
    </div>
<?php
$i++;
}
?>
</div>
```

This is what I want to do:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="holder"> 0 - blue </div>
<div class="holder"> 1 - yellow </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="holder"> 2 - red </div>
<div class="holder"> 3 - pink </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="holder"> 4 - green </div>
<div class="holder"> 5 - cyan </div>
<div class="holder"> 6 - gold </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="holder"> 0 - blue </div>
<div class="holder"> 1 - yellow </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="holder"> 2 - red </div>
<div class="holder"> 3 - pink </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="holder"> 4 - green </div>
<div class="holder"> 5 - cyan </div>
<div class="holder"> 6 - gold </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="holder"> 0 - blue </div>
<div class="holder"> 1 - yellow </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="holder"> 2 - red </div>
<div class="holder"> 3 - pink </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="holder"> 4 - green </div>
<div class="holder"> 5 - cyan </div>
<div class="holder"> 6 - gold </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/ke2-ku8
This is my page right now, the three blocks on top are right, I want my template to have this structure. But I can't find a way to do it for every div I generate with my loop.

Any suggestions would be awesome!

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and where does your currenct code fail you?

Comment: I suggest you used classes and child-selectors. It appears you are trying to have your CSS change according to the div being output. This would keep your code cleaner and easier to manage. I'm suggesting you drop the use of the style attribute.

Comment: this is an example... of course I use classes

Comment: `break` and `continue` will allow you to control the flow of a foreach loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php // Fun testing array
$arr = array("blue", "yellow", "red", "pink", "green", "cyan", "gold", "orange", "magenta","blue", "yellow", "red", "pink", "green", "cyan", "gold", "orange", "magenta","blue", "yellow", "red", "pink", "green", "cyan", "gold", "orange", "magenta");

// Here's where we control the breaks
$breakpoints = array(0,2,4);
// Highest number of rows/items
$max_point = 7;

// Loop through all items
foreach ($arr as $i=>$val) {
    // Track breaks
    $calc = $i% $max_point;
    // Check for a breakpoint to make things happen
    if(in_array($calc,$breakpoints)) {
        // Is this a virgin?
        if ($i > 0) echo "</div>";
        // Output a new container
        echo '<div class="container" style="margin:20px 10px;border:1px solid;">'."\n\r";
    } ?>
    <div class="holder" style="font-family:helvetica;font-weight:bold;padding:5px;background-color:<?php echo $val; ?>;"><?php echo $i." - ".$val; $i++; ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```